# Using gradients with the scss color map - is it possible?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4, and I was wondering while theming my application whether it was possible to use gradients in the `$theme-colors` map.

Example of usage

```
$theme-colors: ( 
    "brand-gradient": background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff 0%, #000 100%);
);
```

so that if I want a button to be gradient i could do

`<button class="btn btn-brand-gradient">Test</button>`

And then aswell as adding the gradient, also using fallbacks for old browsers like you normally would.

Just a curiosity question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. At least not like this.

The `btn` class [uses the values](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.0.0/scss/_buttons.scss#L63) from `$theme-colors` like so:

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
  .btn-#{$color} {
    @include button-variant($value, $value);
  }
}
```

This would normally let you use the class `btn-brand-gradient` as you suggest, if you added the class to `$theme-colors`.

If you [take a look at the mixin](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.0.0/scss/mixins/_buttons.scss#L6) `button-variant()` you'll see that it uses another mixin called `gradient-bg()` for the button background and border.

In [this mixin](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.0.0/scss/mixins/_gradients.scss#L3), the background is set like this:

```
background: $color linear-gradient(180deg, mix($body-bg, $color, 15%), $color) repeat-x;
```

The `$color` argument in a CSS `linear-gradient` must be a valid [color value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value), and a linear-gradient is not in this case.

Comment: So for this to work, I would have to use a solid color - and then all my buttons, etc would be gradient aswell? Atleast that's how I understand the mixins. And to add to my question, is there a way to use gradients only on buttons where it is specified by the specific classes "btn-gradient-primary"?